# I need to link a button to a function in a controller class?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a print button and a print method, i need to link the two?

I need to make the print button call this method, ***public ActionResult Print(int id)***.

I am unsure how to connect the two, i'm sure there are many option i'm just looking for the simplest one, if its adding code to the html or to jQuery i don't mind.

Could some on please show me. Thanks in advance :)

**The create to my button:**

```
<input type="button" value="Print" id="btnPrint" />
```

**And my controller below:**

```
namespace Contract.Controllers
{

    public class ContractController : Controller
    {

        CompassEntities db = new CompassEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<tbSalesContract> contracts = db.sptbSalesContractsGetForUser(Environment.UserName.Trim() + "_comps").AsEnumerable();

            return View(contracts);
        }

        public ActionResult Print(int id)
        {
            return View(""); // This can be removed and Print code may be added
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            tbSalesContract c = new tbSalesContract();
            c.Suretyship = true;
            if (id != null)
            {
                c = db.tbSalesContracts.Find(id);
            }

            ViewBag.UserName = Environment.UserName.Trim();

            //ContractInstance c = new ContractInstance();       
            return View(c);
        }
```

**The action's the Print button can already preform are set with JQuery:**

```
$('#btnPrint').click(function () {     
        if ($('#chkFinal').is(':checked')) {
            $(function () {
                $("#PrintDialog").dialog('close');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#chkFinal').attr('checked', true); // Set finalized. This checkbox is not visible its like a hidden field
            $('#btnSubmit').click(); // Save
        }
```

**What i have at the moment, compiles but does not take me to print method:**

```
// Save, set state to finalized and Print
    $('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {    
        if ($('#chkFinal').is(':checked')) {
            $(function () {
                $("#PrintDialog").dialog('close');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#chkFinal').attr('checked', true); // Set finalized. This checkbox is not visible its like a hidden field
            $('#btnSubmit').click(); // Save
        }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Print","ContractController", new {id = Model.SalesContractId})'
    });
    });
```

Comment: do you want the form to submit to the action? or do you want to do an ajax call after the chkFinal has been validated?

Comment: depends what you want the 'Print' to do.  Do you want it to replace the entire browser window?  Do you want it to update some element within the current window?  Do you want it to offer you a file for download?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams haha, though I think gdoron beat us both :P

Comment: @JasonKulatunga. And the reputation goes to @gdoron... `:)`

Comment: I want to run my print call after the if statement. must just sent though current id

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#btnPrint').click(function() {
    // Call the controller function, put it where you need it.
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Print","ContractController", new {id = Model.SalesContractId})'
    });


    if ($('#chkFinal').is(':checked')) {
        $(function() {
            $("#PrintDialog").dialog('close');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#chkFinal').attr('checked', true); // Set finalized. This checkbox is not visible its like a hidden field
        $('#btnSubmit').click(); // Save
    }​
});
```

Comment: Discussion [moved here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11975/discussion-between-gdoron-and-pomster)

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Thanks what should I do when the comments don't end? In every comment I'm sure it will be the last, but it didn't...

Comment: Hopefully everyone will see my comment and [get the hint.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11975/discussion-between-gdoron-and-pomster)